# Can this be done in one regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regex to match a string that:

- has only digits `0-9` and spaces
- all digits must be same
- should have at-least 2 digits
- should start and end with digits

Matches:

```
11
11111
1  1 1 1 1
1  1
11 1 1 1 1 1
1           1
1    1      1
```

No matches:

```
1             has only one digit
11111         has space at the end
 11111        has space at beginning
12            digits are different
11:           has other character
```

I know regex for each of my requirement. That way I'll use 4 regex
tests. Can we do it in one regex?

Comment: What language and regex processor do you use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it can be done in one regex:

```
^(\d)(?:\1| )*\1$
```

[**Rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/XRg6rOAxbu)

Explanation:

```
^      - Start anchor
(      - Start parenthesis for capturing
 \d    - A digit
)      - End parenthesis for capturing
(?:    - Start parenthesis for grouping only
\1     - Back reference referring to the digit capture before
|      - Or
       - A literal space
)      - End grouping parenthesis
*      - zero or more of previous match
\1     - The digit captured before
$      - End anchor
```

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, \1 up to \9 refer to the value of the corresponding matched block, ordered by opening parenthesis - these are called *backreferences* and are supported in most regular expression engines

Comment: I don't think that does what you think it does: that `\1` inside the character class is not a backref, but a Control-A.

Comment: @Gareth: Not in character classes they don’t!

Comment: No, a `[\\1 ]` is just a literal backslash, a 1, or a space. You cannot have backrefs inside a character class **at all**! I mean no disrespect, but this answer is **wrong**.

Comment: In that case, I wish I hadn't deleted my answer now!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
$_ = "3 33 3 3";
print /^(\d)[\1 ]*\1$/      ? 1 : 0;
print /^(\d)(?:\1| )*\1$/   ? 1 : 0;
```

It produces the output

```
0
1
```

The answer is obvious when you look at the compiled regexes:

```
perl -c -Mre=debug /tmp/a
Compiling REx "^(\d)[\1 ]*\1$"
synthetic stclass "ANYOF[0-9][{unicode_all}]".
Final program:
   1: BOL (2)
   2: OPEN1 (4)
   4:   DIGIT (5)
   5: CLOSE1 (7)
   7: STAR (19)
   8:   ANYOF[\1 ][] (0)
  19: REF1 (21)
  21: EOL (22)
  22: END (0)
floating ""$ at 1..2147483647 (checking floating) stclass ANYOF[0-9][{unicode_all}] anchored(BOL) minlen 1 
Compiling REx "^(\d)(?:\1| )*\1$"
synthetic stclass "ANYOF[0-9][{unicode_all}]".
Final program:
   1: BOL (2)
   2: OPEN1 (4)
   4:   DIGIT (5)
   5: CLOSE1 (7)
   7: CURLYX[1] {0,32767} (17)
   9:   BRANCH (12)
  10:     REF1 (16)
  12:   BRANCH (FAIL)
  13:     EXACT < > (16)
  15:   TAIL (16)
  16: WHILEM[1/1] (0)
  17: NOTHING (18)
  18: REF1 (20)
  20: EOL (21)
  21: END (0)
floating ""$ at 1..2147483647 (checking floating) stclass ANYOF[0-9][{unicode_all}] anchored(BOL) minlen 1 
/tmp/a syntax OK
Freeing REx: "^(\d)[\1 ]*\1$"
Freeing REx: "^(\d)(?:\1| )*\1$"
```

Backrefs are just regular octal characters inside character classes!!

Comment: You cannot use \1 in [], test it:
print 'Your solution=','2 2   2' =~ /^(\d)[\1 ]*\1$/? "True" : "False","\n";
print 'Mine solution=','2 2   2' =~ /^(\d)(\1| )*\1$/? "True" : "False","\n";

Comment: @xt.and.r: Of course you cannot.  That was my point. I do not use `\1` in `[]`.  That is what I was trying to get people to see.

Comment: Ok :) and "?:"  is not required. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d)( *\1)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(\d)(\1| )*\1$/
```